# Share Spring Security Core with various Grails apps

Tags: grails, spring-security

I almost finished the development of two grails apps. The lastest things to implement are authentication and authorization. I'm going to use Spring Security due to Grails's integration. The Spring Security Core plugin was installed in the two apps and works well, but each one has his own database tables (User, Role and User_Role).

To share the database tables, my solution was:

1. Created a database with User, Role and User_Role;
2. Configure a secondary Datasource that access this db;
3. Installed the Spring Security Core Plugin in the two apps;
4. Used the s2-quickstart command in the apps;
5. Mapped the generated user, role and user_role to the datasource that was created previously.

Other solutions that i have analyzed are:

- Create a app with all the user's information to be accessed by RESTful service. Then i would implement a new UserDetailsService to load de user from this service.
- Create a plugin with all the Spring Security domains, controllers, views and conf files.

What's the best approach? I'm using the Spring Security for the first time and didn't realize a more intelligent option.

Answer (score 0):

Probably creating a Grails plugin would be the best option. One of the common use cases for plugins in Grails is to share controllers/services/resources/etc. between multiple projects.